# Is there a way to append new elements to an existing PySimpleGUI window?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm using PySimpleGUI to generate a window with a few hundred inputtext fields pre-filled by a pandas dataframe. I'd like to be able to allow the user to add a an empty set of inputtext fields so they might fill in another row manually. Is there a way to append new inputtext fields to my existing window after creation?

Comment: Try `window.extend_layout(container, rows)`, https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Layout_Extend.py

Comment: That might just work. I'll implement a test and report back.

Comment: Here's a real-world example of Jason's suggestion that I'm running on my desktop now - https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Desktop_Widget_FedEx_Package_Tracking.py  https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/46163555/144759494-5ad3c058-e8da-4bf6-9b9e-126d813331b5.png

Comment: Both of these examples were super helpful! I was able to get it working as a result. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Per Jason and Mike's comments, utilizing extend_layout allowed me to edit the existing window layout without calling the window again or getting a layout re-use error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).